# Linux Bash sed command

Tags: linux, unix, sed

Can somebody explain to me what `/#&/` is doing in this command? `cat /etc/services | sed 's/.*/#&/'  > services.tmp`

Comment: Voting to migrate to SU.

Comment: Did you think to try running this from your home directory?  It would create a new `services.tmp` file which you could examine and not have to post a question here.

Comment: @JimGarrison did you ever think that I'm new to Linux and I didn't know what this would do so I wanted to ask before I changed something on my system.

Comment: My apologies. If you came from a Windows background I can understand you'd be scared.  It's a lot harder to break a Linux system (as long as you're not logged in as root).  You could run this in your home directory and it would create a new file `services.tmp` with the result, which you could then examine.  This doesn't change the fact that this question is off-topic for SO, however.

Answer (score 3):

The `s///` construct does a regular expression replacement.  The search is for zero or more of 
any character `.*`.  The replacement is `#` followed by whatever text was matched.  The effect is to output every line with the `#` prefix.

The equivalent would be this:

```
sed 's/^/#/'
```

The above matches the beginning of a line (but not any characters) and replaces it with `#`.

In both cases, all lines (even empty lines) are matched.

Comment: So in simple terms, it makes every line into a comment?

Comment: Yes, effectively, since `/etc/services` uses `#` as a comment token.  If you wanted to avoid doubling-up the comments, you could use `s/^[^#]/#&/`, which only does the replacement on lines that don't begin with `#`.

Answer (score 2):

It's prepending a `#` to every line.

Comment: So its making every line that has a filename (.something) into a comment?

Comment: @redf150flames No, `.` matches a single character, not a literal dot/period.  You should read about regular expressions.  Also, don't forget that filenames in Linux aren't required to contain a period.  That's a stupid DOS idea that stuck and proliferated into modern Windows.